# ExtJs button absolute position

Tags: button, extjs

I would like to foce show tooltip near a ExtJS button.
for that I'm creating a tooltip object and I'm trying to use ShowAt method.
the ShowAt method gets X,Y coordinates. 
When I'm trying to get the button's absolute position (using top/let offset) I'm getting wrong values.
What is the best way to get the absolute position of an ExtJS button?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/LLGQ2/

```
<div id="buttonContainer" style="position:absolute; width:50px; height:30px; left:100px; top:100px;"></div>
```

Javascript code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.button.Button',{
    text: 'Ok',
    renderTo: 'buttonContainer'
});
```

or like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.button.Button',{
    text: 'Ok',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    style: 'position:absolute; left:100px; top:100px;'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wEUvZ/

Comment: thanks. so just to be sure I understand correctly, I need to place the button a container? why is that?

Comment: I had changed my answer

Comment: thanks. now when I using _renderTo: Ext.getBody()_, the tooltip I assigned to the button doesn't popup. Any Idea? (thanks!)

Comment: Try to change z-index of tooltip - add class with big z-index